# Web App that uses Webcam...any Rails plugins/gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, webcam, rubygems

I;m a developer looking to make an app similar to chat roulette.  I'm pretty comfortable with Ruby on Rails as my platform and would like to program it in that.

The downside is I have no idea about how to do anything using webcams.

Is there a plugin or gem for rails that integrates webcams easily?

Some quick browsing brought me to abobes site...but I haven't used it before, and though I dont mind learning new things, I'd like to get this out quickly so I'd rather stick to what I know.

What you do you use for webcams?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to use a third-party plug-in to interface the webcam with the site. Rails takes care of things on the back-end (finding and connecting users) but you would need to use Flash or something similar to connect the web page with the camera.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but we've been able to use `headshot` gem in one of our apps.

https://github.com/diwadm/headshot

Comment: it's flash based.

Comment: @buncis This question is 11 years old, and my answer 5 years old. If you need a solution, you can try `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`